# RxSwift: Is it safe to always use [unowned self] when a class has a disposeBag property?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I recently found an article that says using `[unowned self]` is always safe as long as you are adding the subscription to a `DisposeBag` and it is inside the view controller.

Assuming I have a ViewController where `deinit` is not being called due to a strong reference:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private var results = Variable<[Item]>([])
    private var searchText = Variable("")
    var selectedCompletion: ((Item) -> Void)!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        results.asObservable()
            .bind(to: tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "CustomCell", cellType: CustomCell.self)) { row, item, cell in
                cell.configure(with: item)
            }
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)

        tableView.rx.itemSelected
            .subscribe(onNext: { ip in
                self.selectedCompletion(self.results.value[ip.row])
                self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            })
            .disposed(by:disposeBag)

        searchBar.rx.text
            .debounce(0.6, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { searchText in
                if searchText == nil || searchText!.isEmpty { return }
                self.search(query: searchText!)
            })
            .disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    private func search(query: String) {
        // Search asynchronously
        search(for: query) { response in

            // Some logic here...
            self.results.value = searchResult.results
        }
    }
}
```

I should simply be able to declare `[unowned self]` in my subscription closures and not have to worry about my app crashing from `self` being `nil`.

Where I'm confused is, because search is asynchronous, doesn't that mean `self` **can** be `nil` if the ViewController has been popped off the navigation stack before the query completes?

Or would the `disposeBag` be deallocated first and the closure wouldn't complete?

Any clarification about how to know whether or not a class owns a closure would be great too.

Comment: I think you can't be sure about it. It depends on the internal implementation and thread race. For example, if http client captured your closure and invoked request, then even if disposeBag cancels the subscription, there still might be a race-condition and http client may invoke your closure just after disposing of self.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's a safe approach to use `unowned` with a dispose bag, except one block - `onDisposed`. There have been the cases when an app crashed because of `unowed` keyword -> `weak` is useful here.

Answer (score 0):

as @kzaher says on github

> you should never use unowned.

sources:

https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources/issues/169
https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1593